# Pretty URL Links for Users

Tags: php

I am trying to make my url **yourwebsite/funusername** from **yourwebsite/profile.php?username=funusername**. I have tried .htaccess like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)$ profile.php?username=$1
```

(I also have code in there to make it take the `.php` out of my pages). I am very inexperienced with .htaccess so any help is very appreciated.

**Bonus:** How would I reference this URL in a link? Such as `<a href="profileurl">`

Comment: I have searched all over the internet for a solution but either nothing is working for me or I couldn't find full code examples.

Comment: Yes, but I'm using PHP variables in the link.

Comment: Okay, but why is the general .htacces code not working?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a page yourwebsite/funusername/index.html and load yourwebsite/profile.php?username=funusername using jQuery load.

Here is a working example:

Code of yourwebsite/funnyusername/index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("html").load("/path/to/profile.php?username=funnyusername");
});
</script>
</html>
```

Then remove the html tags of yourwebsite/account.php.

Also if you have a `<!doctype html>` tag in yourwebsite/account.php remove it too.

E.g:

```
<head>
** Whatewer code you have here **
</head>
<body>
** Whatever code you have here **
</body>
```

**You could also do it with an iframe, but this is how i'd do it**

Comment: I'm on mobile right now, so i can't but i'm doing It as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's extremely appreciated. I feel it's necessary for my type of site to have just the username looking like the page's name.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long, here is the example code.